# How to store the original form of a variable?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to store the original version of a variable in Javascript. If that variable changes, it doesn't affect the stored original value, and the script will compare the old version of the variable and the new one together. I want to call a function that stores the original value of the variable, but if something that happens that causes it to change the system will know that the new variable isn't right and replace it with the old one. Is this possible without a database?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you explain what problem this is supposed to solve? If you're asking for behavior languages don't typically support, there's [probably a better way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676) to achieve whatever you're really trying to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: Just copy the original value of the variable to another variable. `const orig_variable = variable;`. Then you can later do `if (variable !== orig_variable)`

Comment: But if you don't want the variable to change, why don't you just declare it with `const`? Then any attempt to reassign the variable will fail.

Comment: Seconding the notion of this potentially being an XY problem. Taken at face value, you can use localStorage to retain values beyond a page reload. This will only store them for one user though, and only in the current browser.

Comment: If you wouldn't deal each element then just Serialize form element and value then encode string and keep in one string variable,(but be careful if your elements have huge of amount data then you can keep as array element) when restore data and rewind decode and desrialize it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a concept similar to [`observable` in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/observable.html):

```js
class Observable {
    constructor(value, onChanged) {
        this._value = value;
        this._onChanged = onChanged;
    }

    set value(v) {
        if (this._onChanged(this._value, v)) {
            this._value = v;
        }
    }

    get value() {
        return this._value;
    }
}
```

You can use it as:

```js
// Creates a new Observable with initial value 2
const obs = new Observable(2, (oldValue, newValue) => {
    // Only update the underlying value if the parity of the current value
    // is different from the parity of the value to be updated.
    // This is only an example, you can put your logic here.
    return oldValue % 2 !== newValue % 2;
});

console.log(obs.value);   // value=2 (initial value)
obs.value = 4;
console.log(obs.value);   // value=2 (2 is even and 4 is even, don't update)
obs.value = 5;
console.log(obs.value);   // value=5 (2 is even and 5 is odd, update)
obs.value = 7;
console.log(obs.value);   // value=5 (5 is odd and 7 is odd, don't update)
obs.value = 8;
console.log(obs.value);   // value=8 (5 is odd and 8 is even, update)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use **local storage** or **sessionStorage** to persist variables without using databases, but only the browser local capabilities.

Here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp you can find a detailed explanation about how using those features.

Keep in mind that **sessionStorage** content will be lost when you will close the browser, instead the **local storage** will persist data based on an expiration timeout you will provide for each storage entry.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, what you want is not possible exactly, maybe [object variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Variables) might be the right choice for you.

Comment: This is an answer. It says it is not possible